# Get Wordpress posts data with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I work on a WorPress site and I want to have only 4 posts on my page and navigate betwen other posts with ajax.

I have my front-page.php (simply code for try):

```
<section>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="btn_next">+</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="btn_pre">-</button>
  <div class="" id="result"></div>
  <div class="" id="offset"></div>
</section>
```

I have my ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $("#btn_next").click(function(){
    var off = $('#offset').html();
    data_ajax(1);
  })
  $("#btn_pre").click(function(){
    data_ajax(-1);
  });

  function data_ajax(new_offset){
    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxObject.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        action : 'ajax_agenda',
      },
      success: function(responseText){
        console.log("result : " + JSON.stringify(responseText));
        $("#result").html('<h3>résultats</h3>');
      },
      error: function(xhr, error, exception){
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(error);
        console.log(exception);
        $("#result").html('<h3>Pas de résultats</h3>');
      }
    }); // fin ajax
  }

});
```

and my function in function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_agenda', 'ajax_agenda');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_agenda', 'ajax_agenda');
function ajax_agenda(){

  $final_array = array();

  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3, /* how many post you need to display */
    'offset' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'agenda', /* your post type name */
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $posts = $query->posts;

    if($query->have_posts()){
        $final_array["success"] = "true";
        $final_array["results"] = $posts;
  }
  else{
    $final_array["success"] = "false";
  };

  echo json_encode( $final_array );


    die(); // Pour eviter les erreurs due au "die(0)"" prédrnt dans le fichier "admin-ajax.php"
};
```

But I don't arrived to use datas return by js :(
I need your help pls.

Ty

Comment: Why are you passing a `new_offset` parameter in your `data_ajax` calls, only to then do absolutely nothing with that passed value inside of the function?

Comment: I didn't put it on because I'll treat it later

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code

```
function get_ajax_posts_data() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('yout post type'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
    );

    $ajaxposts = get_posts( $args );
    echo json_encode( $ajaxposts );

}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts_data', 'get_ajax_posts_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_posts_data', 'get_ajax_posts_data');
```

jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { action : 'get_ajax_posts_data' },
    success: function( response ) {
        $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
            console.log( key, value ); 
        } );
    }
});
```